# Spring4.3.0 integration with Hiberbnate 5

Tags: spring, hibernate

In Hibernate 5 bootstrapping api is changed by introducing BootStrapServiceRegistry class, now how can I bootstrap the sessionFactoryBean from spring context.xml file . Please provide me on approaches for xml bootstrapping rather than programmatic way that's explained in docs.

Currently we have spring 4 and hibernate 4 integration in the context.xml and we are planning to migrate to Hibernate 5. We are facing challenges with LocalSessionFactoryBean, getting No qualifying bean exceptions for the serices, which is thrown by another exception like no qualifying bean JtaTransaction Manager

Comment: Replace `hibernate4` with `hibernate5` and well that basically is it from a spring perspective. If you want a better answer provide a better question with more information.

Comment: I replaced the LocalSessionFactoryBean with hibernate 5 but still the components are not getting injected. I have set the coordinator class instead of factory class in hibernate properties

Comment: As mentioned if you want a better answer provide more and precise question.